# How to populate multiple sqlite tables from a single xml file?

Tags: java, android, xml, sqlite

I've been able to successfully bring in data to a single table, but need to bring data for several tables.  Is it possible to do this from a single xml file?

```
    //Open xml file
    XmlResourceParser _xml = res.getXml(R.xml.animals_records);
    try
    {
        //Check for end of document
        int eventType = _xml.getEventType();
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            //Search for record tags
            if ((eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) &&(_xml.getName().equals("record"))){
                //Record tag found, now get values and insert record
                String _Title = _xml.getAttributeValue(null, TITLE);
                String _Color = _xml.getAttributeValue(null, COLOR, 0);
                _Values.put(TITLE, _Title);
                _Values.put(COLOR, _Color);
                db.insert(TABLENAME1, null, _Values);             
            }
            if ((eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) &&(_xml.getName().equals("trees"))){
                //Record tag found, now get values and insert record
                String _Title = _xml.getAttributeValue(null, FAMILY);
                String _Color = _xml.getAttributeValue(null, SPECIES, 0);
                _Values.put(FAMILY, _Title);
                _Values.put(SPECIES, _Color);
                db.insert(TABLENAME2, null, _Values);             
            }
            eventType = _xml.next();
        }
    }
```

With an XML that looks something like this:

```
    <animals>
        <record title="Dog" color="Brown" />
        <record title="Cat" color="Gray" />
        <record title="Rabbit" color="White" />
        <record title="Spider" color="Black" />
        <trees family="Hardwood" species="Oak" />
        <trees family="Soft" color="Pine" />
     </animals>
```

Any ideas?  Obvious faults?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that XML structure.

Comment: What 's the problem you have? Because I can see the answer in your question.